# get the output of the remote execution of the SSH command

Tags: node.js, express, ssh

I work with expressJs and to execute a remote SSH command I use the 'simple-ssh', this code allows to execute the command except that I could not get the result of the display outside this block.

```
ssh.exec('ls Documents/versions', {
out: function(stdout) {
    arrayOfVersion = stdout.split("\n");}}).start();
```

How to get the content of arrayOfVersion and manipulate it after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function which creates arrayofVersion async, you won't be able access it outside of this scope without some sort of waiting process which waits until the variable has a value.

You can do this in a few ways, to begin with I would recommend researching how nodejs handles async functions as this is a big part of nodejs. Generally you would use one of the following: callbacks, promises, or async/await.

With any of those techniques, you should be able to run your SSH code and then continue on with the result of the stdout.